# JavaFX 8: How to remove the last white pixel from the combobox list

Tags: java, css, javafx, combobox, javafx-8

Is it possible to remove that white line with CSS?

[image]

Comment: Yes its possible . before ask how ? please provide your code ?

Comment: @user2486 It's the original combobox. The code is: ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox();

Answer (score 0):

You can try something in 'list-cell:empty'.
Changing background color of 'list-cell:empty' changes color of this white line to default 'focus-color'

```
.list-cell:empty {
    -fx-padding: 0 ;
    -fx-background-color: -fx-focus-color ;
    -fx-background-insets: 0 ;

}
```